# Serialize return false in WordPress custom query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to unserialize data, but it always returns false.
My serialize data is in the form below:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:2:"12";i:1;s:2:"13";}
```

My unserialize code:

```
$option_ids      = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT option_id FROM $floor_plans_tbl WHERE plan_id = $plan_id" );
$uns_option_ids  = unserialize( $option_ids[0] );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `get_results` by default returns an object but you are trying to access an array. Add the `ARRAY_A` argument to this call to make it return an array.

So your new code:

```
$option_ids      = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT option_id FROM $floor_plans_tbl WHERE plan_id = $plan_id", ARRAY_A );
$uns_option_ids  = unserialize( $option_ids[0] );
```

Comment: We need to add the return type in the get_results function. We can also use ARRAY_N for this return type. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an output type.
you used an array type and that's why you need to add ARRAY on `$wpdb->get_results` and check the following code to see how we can add attributes to this function:

```
 $option_ids= $wpdb->get_results( 'query', output_type );
```

Use this "output_type":

`ARRAY_A` - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of associative arrays, using column names as keys.
or 
`ARRAY_N` - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of numerically indexed arrays.

```
> $option_ids= $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT option_id FROM
> $floor_plans_tbl WHERE plan_id = $plan_id", "ARRAY_A" );
```

or

```
> $option_ids= $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT option_id FROM
> $floor_plans_tbl WHERE plan_id = $plan_id", "ARRAY_N" );
```

I hope, it helps you out!